# How to get a count of a group within a group in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, grouping

I have an Access report that I would like to output like this :

```
Group 1 : Client : Cient Name - Contanct, etc
Group 2: WO : #WO - Date, etc. 

Detail : 
Item1
Item2
...
ItemN

End Group 2: Total for WO : Total, etc
End Group 1: Total for Client : Count(WO) and total
```

I cannot get the Count(WO) part right. Is there any way to do this and if so how ?

Edit : Just so everyone understands, if I have 3 WO for one client and 15 lines total for the client, I want Count(wo) to be 3, not 15.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the report wizard? It should guide you through creating such a report. The group footer should have a textbox with:

```
=Count([WO])
```

EDIT Re Comment

Add a textbox to the group header and set the `Running Sum` property to `Over Group`, the `Visible` property to `No`, the `Control Source` to `=1` and the `Name` to, say, `GroupCount`. In a suitable footer, create another textbox and set the `Control Source` to `=GroupCount`.

Comment: Doesn't work. I am pretty familiar with access so that was the first thing I tried and it gives me 15, instead of 3...

Comment: @David Brunelle I have added some further notes.

Comment: Dang, I did it before but coudln't remember. I'll try it this morning.