# MS Access How to Count Unique Records or Values On a Filtered Report

Tags: ms-access, expression, unique-values, ms-access-reports

All,

I have a query called "WCR_Q" and a report called "WCR_R" based off of this query.  My report is filtered based off a record selection from a form.  When I use the expression =Count[FacilityID] becuse I get a total number of records in the query instead of the total number of records as displayed in my report.  The query has (6) records for [FacilityID] but there's only (2) [FacilityID] in my report.  This is due to the query having duplicates.  I need an expression formula to place in my control that will count only unique records in the query or *only count the records expressed on the report*.

I've tried:

```
 =Count([FacilityID])
 =DCount("[FacilityID]","WCR_Q",DCount("[FacilityID]","WCR_Q","FacilityID =" & [FacilityId])>0)
 =DCount("[FacilityID]","WCR_Q","FacilityID =" & [FacilityID])
 =DCount("[FacilityID","[WCR_Q]","[FacilityID]=" & [FacilityID])>0
 =Count(IIf("FacilityID <>" & [FacilityID],0))
 =DCount("[FacilityID]","WCR_Q",[FacilityID])
 =DCount("[FacilityID]","WCR_Q","FacilityID <>" & [FacilityID])
```

I have tried the count functions in the Facility grouping and the Campaign grouping and it returns a value of (6) instead of (2) expressed in report.

I'm new to writing expressions and designing reports in Access so please help if anyone knows how to count unique values in a control box.  Thanks!!!

Comment: Too much info.  No need for images of report, neither design nor print version, since these really don't add anything to information about underlying record source for which you want a record count.  If anything, the actual SQL query text from the report RecordSource would be appropriate.

Comment: I suppose that none of the attempts worked, because you are basing all counting attempts on the query `WCR_Q` which you already state has duplicate values for the field you want to count.  Instead of programming by variations until it works (because if you don't understand why it works, it may likely be incorrect in future runs), consider what you are asking the function to return: *No calls to Count or DCount can request a count of **distinct** values*.  You would need another query which counts the distinct values. See http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/dcount-distinct-values-t1831303.html

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084318/how-to-get-a-count-of-a-group-within-a-group-in-access-2007.  The basic idea is to create a "dummy" control in the grouped-by header, then add up (i.e. count) every instance that the dummy control is included in the report.  That sum will represent the count of the grouped field.  I think this will only work with the count in the report footer, however.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much C. Perkins.  I spent so much time trying to figure out a solution to this. Thank you for your time to post the reply.

Here's what I DID:  Add a textbox to the group header and set the Running Sum property to Over Group, the Visible property to No, the Control Source to =1 and the Name to, say, GroupCount.  I created another textbox in the header and set the Control Source to =GroupCount.

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
DCount("[ITEM_BAL_QRY]![ITEM_CD] ","[ITEM_BAL_QRY]"," [ITEM_BAL_QRY]![ITEM_CD] = [ITEM_Code]")>1
```

Counting from the source query of the form and I have good result