# MS Access: ReportView Shows Different Value Than PrintView

Tags: ms-access, printing, group-by, report, counting

I have a report that calculates total records by assigning (1) to each then totaling them as discussed here: [MS Access How to Count Unique Records or Values On a Filtered Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53182120/ms-access-how-to-count-unique-records-or-values-on-a-filtered-report?noredirect=1#comment93256316_53182120).

The total is reported in the Report Header and works great when I open the report arriving at the correct number; however, when I print the value changes.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Please try to place the total in the reports footer, just for testing. Is it still 1 when printing?

Comment: @UnhandledException Yes.  Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that might come behind me...    It will not work.  I tried every possible method then paid for help.  What we did instead was setup a make table query.  The button that opens the report produces a temporary table.  That table is setup as a crossflow table and calculates the totals.  Those totals are then linked to the report from the temporary table.  Works perfectly.